# An isomorphism betwenn SO(3) and $T_1 S^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, proof-verification

So, I have been working on the next problem:

Let be $SO(3)=\lbrace A\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3} / A A^t=A^t A= I$ and $ \det(A)>0 \rbrace $ and $T=\lbrace (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2 / |x|=|y|=1$ and $\langle x,y\rangle=0\rbrace $. Let now be $A=(x|y|z)\in SO(3)$ be a matrix in SO(3) whose colums are the vectors $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3),y=(y_1,y_2,y_3),z=(z_1,z_2,z_3)$. Then, the rule that asignes the first to colums of $A$ to the element $(x,y)\in T$ is an homeomorphism.

SO far, I have proven that it is well defined and, assuming its bijectivity, that it is, indeed, and homeomorphism. Still, I find myself unable of finding an argument that proofs the bijectivity that satisfies me enough to consider that I have actually proven it. I will now, tell what I have done, so that you can give me a hint on what I am missing or thinking in a wrong way:

Let $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}^3$ be orthonormal among them and let  $A=(x|y|z)$. I want to prove that $A$ belongs to $SO(3)$. In that sense, I have tried using the main definition given above of $SO(3)$, with what I do not get to prove that $A A^t =I$ (regardless that $A^t A=I$ is trivial).

I have also tried using that if $A\in SO(3)$ then $\det(A)=1$, but I am not sure how to do it that way.

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough for $x,y,z $ to be orthonormal for $A= (x|y|z)$ to be in $SO(3)$ : it just lands you in $O(3)$.

Take $A=(x_1|x_2|x_3)$ to be any $3\times 3$ matrix. If you compute $A^T A$, you will see that in position $ij$, what you get is exactly $\langle x_i ,x_j \rangle$.

It follows that $A^TA = I_3$ if and only if $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is an orthonormal basis, that is, $A\in O(3)$ if and only if $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ are orthonormal.

But now you want to get $SO(3)$, not just $O(3)$ ! That's where bijectivity comes from, otherwise given $x, y$, you have multiple choices for $z$.

Now here's how you get bijectivity : given $x,y$ with $|x|=|y| = 1, \langle x,y \rangle = 0$, there are two $z$'s such that $(x,y,z)$ is orthonormal : the reason is that any such $z$ has to be in $x_1^\bot \cap x_2^\bot$ which is the intersection of two different (why are they different ?) hyperplanes, so has dimension $1$.

Therefore there is $z_0$ such that any such $z$ is of the form $\lambda z_0$ for some $\lambda$. But $z$ has to have norm $1$ : that reduces $\lambda$ to two options: $\frac{1}{|z_0|}, - \frac{1}{|z_0}$. That is, we get $z$ and $-z$.

For both of these, $(x\mid y \mid z)$ is in $O(3)$, and we have $\det (x| y| z) = - \det(x|y|-z)$. In other words: exactly one of these two has determinant $1$ ($\iff$ positive determinant given that we're in $O(3)$). That only leaves one choice.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, but the part I do not see to be obvious is that if ypu have an orthonormal basis, then the matrix whos colums are those vectors is, indeed, in $O(3)$. Do you know anywhere I could find a proof of it?

Comment: For that you just have to do the computation I mentioned : write down what the $ij$ coordinate of $A^TA$ is in terms of the $x_i$, you will see what you get

Comment: For your matrix $A$, consider $A^t A$; the $ij$ entry is the dot product of $x_i$ and $x_j$! So it's $0$ for $i \ne j$, and $1$ for $i = j$, so $A^t A$ is the identity. All you used was that the $x_i$ are pairwise orthogonal, and unit length.

Comment: Yes, that implication is obvious, but you want to proof $A A^t=I$ as matrices are non-conmutative, or am I wanting to proof more than I need?

Comment: For square matrices, if $AB = I_n$, then $BA=I_n$ too

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot the unicity of the inverse element on a ring hahahahaha. Thank you two very much for your help and time!!

Comment: It's more subtle than just uniqueness of inverse elements : there are some noncommutative rings with $ab =1 $ but not $ba =1$, this is a special property of matrices ! It follows from the fact that if $AB=I_n$, then $A$ is surjective, therefore it is an isomorphism (by dimension theory, but actually it holds over any commutative ring), and so now we may invoke uniqueness of inverses